# Same app name in itunes store?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, itunes

I want to understand how is Youtube and Facebook app have same name for iPhone and iPad in the  itunes store?

I am trying to submit an app (different build) for iPhone (approved & live with name eg: MYAPPNAME) and now iPad but its not allowing me to use the same name (i.e. MYAPPNAME) to be displayed in the itunes store.

I understand that i can use MYAPPNAME FOR IPAD but how did youtube & facebook get the same names?

Please help I need to submit the app at the earliest.

[image: iPhone App on Itunes]
[image: iPad app on itunes with same name]

Regards, 
Shoeb

Comment: You should ask them (apple, not google or facebook)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are the same app. They are universal apps with the same bundle identifier. A reference is here http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/ios-app-builder/better-code-develop-universal-apps-for-ios-devices/.

Comment: Great information for future projects. However, for this app, it will be more than 20+ MB due to the retina support for iphone and ipad so i will submit it as seperate apps for now. Works for me

Comment: @ShoebSurya Just a reminder, as of iOS 6, your limit to worry about is 50MB. See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4401913 and considering the small amount of users still on iOS 5, it is not really an issue to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

Don't submit different apps for Ipad and Iphone.

Make a Universal App that work on both iPad and iPhone. And using same bundle identifier, just update your live app with this app.